# How to compare two querysets in Django templating?

Tags: python, html, django, for-loop, django-templates

This might sound super similar to other postings about comparing two querysets using `zip` and other choices, but I have been reading lots and none of them gave me a good idea what I can do for the comparing I need.

To start off, I am getting queries from the database and in the HTML templating I need to generate some defaults for `select` element. With one default it is easy, but with `multiple` I am having trouble since there's no `break` in Django templating.

Let's say I have these two querysets that I get returned from the backend:

```
[<J: j1>, <J: j2>, <J: j3>, <J: j4>]
[<J: j2>, <J: j4>]
```

I tried something like this to start with, and I can understand that it's looping more than needed, so I am getting more outputs than needed too. I tried searching for something that would break the loop, but I figured there's no breaking up the loop in a Django template.

```
<select name="" id="">
    {% for j in all_j %}
        {% for s in all_s %}
            {% if j.id == s.id %}
                <option value="{{ j.id }}" selected="selected">{{ j.name }}</option>
            {% else %}
                <option value="{{ j.id }}">{{ j.name }}</option>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

I tried other ways such as

```
<select name="" id="">
    {% for s in all_s %}
        {% if s in all_j %}
            <option value="{{ j.id }}" selected="selected">{{ j.name }}</option>
        {% else %}
            <option value="{{ j.id }}">{{ j.name }}</option>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Then I figured it only gets output if it's true, that things in `else` will not run.

Can someone give me an idea or know what I can do with this kind of situation?

below is what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: I'm not going to provide this as an answer because it isn't exactly what you asked for, but as a design choice I'd very much consider moving this out to a template tag (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/) or just doing it in your view code and providing the result in the template context.

Comment: if you really want to do this in template, then make your own template filters, http://www.pfinn.net/custom-django-filter-tutorial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def home(request):
    context = {
        'all_s': ['j1', 'j2', 'j3', 'j4'],
        'all_j': ['j2', 'j4']
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<header>
    <title></title>
</header>
<body>
<select name="bla" id="" multiple style="width: 200px;">
    {% for s in all_s %}
        {% if s in all_j %}
            <option value="{{ s }}" selected="selected">{{ s }}</option>
        {% else %}
            <option value="{{ s }}">{{ s }}</option>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: arg, no wonder you mentioned my solution should work.  I was messing myself up with the variable names >.<" this is perfect...thx thx